# Ошибка при помещении начальных данных Админа в приложение ASP.NET CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    IConfigurationRoot Configuration;

    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(opt =>
        {
            opt.ViewLocationExpanders.Add(new RazorViewExpander());
        });

        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => { options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login"; });

        services.AddDbContext<JobsStoreDbContext>(options =>{
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:JobsStore:ConnectionString"]);
        });

        // Add Identity services to the services container
        services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<JobsStoreDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddSingleton<IJobsRepository, EFJobsRepository>();

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        services.AddMemoryCache();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseAuthentication();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        JobsStoreDbContext.CreateAdminAccount(app.ApplicationServices, Configuration).Wait();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

    }
}
```

}

Файл JobsStoreDbContext:

```
public static async Task CreateAdminAccount(IServiceProvider serviceProvider,
    IConfiguration configuration)
{
    UserManager<AppUser> userManager = serviceProvider
        .GetRequiredService<UserManager<AppUser>>();
    RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager = serviceProvider
        .GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();

    string username = configuration["Data:AdminAccount:Name"];
    string email = configuration["Data:AdminAccount:Email"];
    string password = configuration["Data:AdminAccount:Password"];
    string role = configuration["Data:AdminAccount:Role"];

    if (await userManager.FindByNameAsync(username) == null)
    {
        if (await roleManager.FindByNameAsync(role) == null)
        {
            await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(role));
        }
        AppUser user = new AppUser()
        {
            UserName = username,
            Email = email
        };

        IdentityResult result =
            await userManager.CreateAsync(user, password);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, role);
        }
    }
}
```

Ну собственно сама ошибка :

> An error occurred while starting the application. AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Cannot resolve
>   scoped service
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Jobs.Models.AppUser]'
>   from root provider.) System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(int
>   millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>
> InvalidOperationException: Cannot resolve scoped service
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Jobs.Models.AppUser]'
>   from root provider.
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteValidator.ValidateResolution(Type
>   serviceType, IServiceScope scope, IServiceScope rootScope)
>
> AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Cannot resolve
>   scoped service
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Jobs.Models.AppUser]'
>   from root provider.) System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(int
>   millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
>   Jobs.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment
>   env) in Startup.cs
>   +
>               JobsStoreDbContext.CreateAdminAccount(app.ApplicationServices,
>   Configuration).Wait();
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder
>   app)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISSetupFilter+<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder
>   app)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter+<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder
>   app)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.AutoRequestServicesStartupFilter+<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder
>   builder)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
>
> Show raw exception details InvalidOperationException: Cannot resolve
>   scoped service
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Jobs.Models.AppUser]'
>   from root provider.
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteValidator.ValidateResolution(Type
>   serviceType, IServiceScope scope, IServiceScope rootScope)
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.IServiceProviderEngineCallback.OnResolve(Type
>   serviceType, IServiceScope scope)
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type
>   serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type
>   serviceType)
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type
>   serviceType)
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider
>   provider, Type serviceType)
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider
>   provider)
>   Jobs.Models.JobsStoreDbContext.CreateAdminAccount(IServiceProvider
>   serviceProvider, IConfiguration configuration) in
>   JobsStoreDbContext.cs
>   +
>               UserManager userManager = serviceProvider

Comment: Была бы метка c#, полагаю, было бы решение получено раньше. Сейчас чисто случайно увидел вопрос.

Comment: @АндрейNOP аналогично, случайно наткнулся

Comment: @tym32167, не удивительно, метка уже добавлена и вопрос поднят :)